# What is the correct way of using flow_images_from_directory() with fit() in keras/tensorflow in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with the dogs vs. cats dataset from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/overview). This is my code, where I

1. Load the data and split it in train/val/test
2. Build the CNN architecture
3. Prepare train/val/test images with `flow_images_from_directory()`
4. Fit the model

```
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github(sprintf("rstudio/%s", c("reticulate", "tensorflow", "keras")))
# reticulate::miniconda_uninstall() # start with a blank slate
# reticulate::install_miniconda()
# keras::install_keras()

# load required packages
rm(list=ls())

setwd("D:/OneDrive/School/Master 2/Predictive and Prescriptive Analytics/05_Exercises")
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
p_load(tensorflow)
p_load(keras)
p_load(tidyverse)

# 1. Read in data
# remove comments if this is the first time splitting the data
original_dataset_dir <- "./train/train"
base_dir <- "./cats_and_dogs"
# dir.create(base_dir)

train_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "train")
# dir.create(train_dir)

validation_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "validation")
# dir.create(validation_dir)

test_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "test")
# dir.create(test_dir)

train_cats_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "cats")
# dir.create(train_cats_dir)

train_dogs_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "dogs")
# dir.create(train_dogs_dir)

validation_cats_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "cats")
# dir.create(validation_cats_dir)

validation_dogs_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "dogs")
# dir.create(validation_dogs_dir)

test_cats_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "cats")
# dir.create(test_cats_dir)

test_dogs_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "dogs")
# dir.create(test_dogs_dir)

# fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
# file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
#           file.path(train_cats_dir))
# 
# fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1001:1500, ".jpg")
# file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
#           file.path(validation_cats_dir))
# 
# fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1501:2000, ".jpg")
# file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
#           file.path(test_cats_dir))
# 
# fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
# file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
#           file.path(train_dogs_dir))
# 
# fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1001:1500, ".jpg")
# file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
#           file.path(validation_dogs_dir))
# 
# fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1501:2000, ".jpg")
# file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
#           file.path(test_dogs_dir))


# 2. Build and compile a CNN
size = c(56,56)
epochs = 10
batch_size = 64
input_shape = c(size, 1)

cnn <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu",
                input_shape = input_shape) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3, 3), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax")

cnn %>%
  compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
          metrics = c("accuracy", keras$metrics$AUC()))

cnn


# 3. Image from directory generators
data_gen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)

train_gen = flow_images_from_directory(train_dir, 
                                       data_gen,
                                       target_size=size,
                                       class_mode='binary',
                                       classes=c('dogs', 'cats'),
                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                       shuffle = TRUE)

val_gen = flow_images_from_directory(validation_dir, 
                                     data_gen,
                                     target_size=size,
                                     class_mode='binary',
                                     classes=c('dogs', 'cats'),
                                     batch_size=batch_size,
                                     shuffle = TRUE)

test_gen = flow_images_from_directory(test_dir, 
                                      data_gen,
                                      target_size=size,
                                      class_mode='binary',
                                      classes=c('dogs', 'cats'),
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      shuffle = TRUE)

# # plot an image 
# plot(as.raster(train_gen[[1]][[1]][17,,,]))
# 
# # inspect a batch
# str(train_gen[[1]])


# 4. Fit CNN
history_cnn <- cnn %>%
  fit(train_gen,
      steps_per_epoch = train_gen$n/batch_size,
      epochs = epochs,
      verbose = 1)
```

I can inspect the `train_gen` object and see that the `flow_images_from_directory()` did in fact return a list of tensors, but when calling `fit()`, it throws the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Boris\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 918, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you have defined 2 units with softmax activation function in the last layer

Replacing this

```
 layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax")
```

with this will solve the error

```
 layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

As it is a binary classification model, the units in the output layer must be equal to 1 with sigmoid as the activation function.
Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!